cnn model gives me an over fitting problem
hello everyone this is the model that i am working on it i am trying to do classification to some document to predict if it has signature or not but every time it gives me an overfitting.
len(signature)
train_size = int(len(signature)*.7)
val_size= int(len(signature)*.2)+1
test_size =len(signature)-train_size-val_size

train= signature.take(train_size)
val=signature.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test=signature.skip(train_size+val_size).take(test_size)

train
model= Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())


model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

Dropout(0.2)

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile('adam',loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

logdir='logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=20, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])


pre = Precision()
re = Recall()
acc = BinaryAccuracy()

for batch in test.as_numpy_iterator():
  x,y = batch
  yhat = model.predict(x)
  pre.update_state(y,yhat)
  acc.update_state(y,yhat)
  re.update_state(y,yhat)
print(f'Precision:{pre.result().numpy()},Recall:{re.result().numpy()},Accuracy:{ acc.result().numpy()}')

img = cv2.imread('/ts1.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

resize = tf.image.resize(img, (256,256))
plt.imshow(resize.numpy().astype(int))
plt.show()

yhat = model.predict(np.expand_dims(resize/255, 0))
yhat

if yhat > 0.5:
    print(f'Predicted class is Yes, it has a signature')
else:
    print(f"Predicted class is NO,it doesn't have a signature")



i used the drop out(0.2) after the 3rd conv layer
also i tried to use early stopping instead of tensorboard call back
i used 5,10,20 epochs in a different times
